# Splunk: Extract string and convert it to date format

Tags: date, splunk

I have such events:

```
something;<id>abc123<timeStamp>2021-12-10T23:10:12.044Z<timeStamp>2021-12-10T23:08:55.278Z>
```

I want to extract the `Id` `abc123` and the two `timeStamp`s.

```
index = something 
|rex field=_raw "id>(?<Id>[0-9a-z-]+)" 
|rex "timeStamp>(?<timeStamp>[T0-9-\.:Z]+)"
| table _time Id timeStamp
```

This works with the query above. But what I struggle now is to convert the `timeStamp`-string to date format to get at the end the `min(timeStamp)` extracted in order to compute the difference between the event's `_time` and the `min(timeStamp)` by the `id` field. I am struggling because of the special format of the timestamp with `T` and `Z` included in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special about those timestamps - they're in standard form.  Use the `strptime` function to convert them.

```
index = something 
|rex field=_raw "id>(?<Id>[^\<]+)" 
|rex "timeStamp>(?<timeStamp>[^\<]+)"
| eval ts = strptime(timeStamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N%Z")
| eval diff = ts - _time
| table _time Id timeStamp diff
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out strftime.org, and the related [`strptime` function](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/DateandTimeFunctions#strptime.28X.2CY.29) used with [`eval`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eval)

Something on the order of this (pulled the microseconds out of your [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex), since Unix epoch time has no concept of subsecond intervals):

```
| rex field=_raw "timeStamp\>(?<timeStamp>[^\.]+)\.\d+Z"
| eval unixepoch=strptime(timeStamp,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```